# How to redirect stdin to file in C with win32 API?

Tags: c, winapi, io-redirection

I am trying to redirect stdin to a file of my choosing, inside a C program ( win32 API) leaving the possibility of redirecting stderr or stdout aswell.

I am writing a shell that I m running on cygwin, the desired efect would be to have cat < file
working.

This is my code so far:

```
    static HANDLE createinputHandle(PCSTR filename, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa)
    {
            return CreateFile(
                 filename,
                 GENERIC_READ,
                 FILE_SHARE_READ,
                 NULL,
                 OPEN_ALWAYS,
                 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                 NULL);
    }


    static VOID RedirectHandle(STARTUPINFO *psi, HANDLE hFile, INT opt)
    {
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            return;

        psi->dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

        switch (opt) {
        case STD_INPUT_HANDLE:
            psi->hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
            psi->hStdInput = hFile;
            break;
        case STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE:
            psi->hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            psi->hStdOutput = hFile;
            break;
        case STD_ERROR_HANDLE:
            psi->hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
            psi->hStdError = hFile;
            break;
        }

command_func() {
 STARTUPINFO si;
 PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
 bool result;
 DWORD wait_result;
 HANDLE inHandle, outHandle, errHandle;
 SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

 ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si)); //macro to init with zero's
 si.cb = sizeof(si);
 ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
 ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));
 sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

 inHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
 outHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
 errHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

     if(inputFile != NULL) {

        inHandle = createinputHandle(inputFile, sa);
            SetHandleInformation(inHandle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT);
            //added
        RedirectHandle(&si, inHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

     }


result = CreateProcess(
            NULL,
            cmd, /*if you want to test this, you need to change cmd to something like "ls -l" */
            NULL,
            NULL,
            TRUE,
            0,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &si,
            &pi); 
}
```

this stdin redirection does not work, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You almost there :) use :`::SetHandleInformation(inHandle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT);`

Comment: check the code again, I edited it adding what you said, I either didn't understand what you said or I am doing something else wrong

Comment: uhm, I just said in my first comment that it doesn't work. I am also closing the handles after create process, so that's not the issue

Comment: Sorry about that, so on the top of my suggestion, open the file w/ NULL security attribute at the 4th param of CreateFile)

Comment: What is the ret value from createinputHandle() ? did you made sure its a valid handle ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27247/discussion-between-pandrei-and-shmil-the-cat)